# Django SQL Server query better way to fetch 100k records

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models

I have a SQL Server database from where I need to fetch the records of about 100k. Then this record is shown in the dashboard and each operation in record is saved to the PostgreSQL database which is the main database of Django. What is the best way to fetch the SQL Server records, fetching every time 100k records or is there is any way to store the query results to speed up the dashboard data view.

Comment: We have not nearly enough information to say anything about this. How fast/slow is your query that fetches your 100k rows ? I mean, when I fetch that amount of rows from a single table it can take just a second or 2, if I need joins and subqueries and so on that is a different story. About fetching rows in batches, lookup pagination there are lots of examples in google

Comment: How can 100K rows be useful in a dashboard? Most people will be happy with 10, maybe 100. I don't know anyone who can grok 200K records.

Comment: Sounds like you’re missing some aggregation in the SQL. It’ll be much faster to do it in the DB then transfer all records over the wire to be aggregated somewhere else